# JavaFX: Artifact displays empty window only

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, javafx

Preface: I am pretty new to JavaFX

Made an simple image resizing application and need to build an artifact of the application.
Using IntelliJ and Eclipse (tried both), i built normal JAR artifacts and JavaFX artifacts. Both are executable, **but only show an empty window.**

When starting the application out of the IDE, there is no problem; the window containing all subpanes get displayed as they should.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Attached code of the application initialization part and a picture of the resulting windows - maybe it helps.

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;

private SettingsViewController settingController;
private MainViewController mainViewController;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("SimpleImageResizer");

    this.primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:icon.png"));

    this.primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(we -> ConfigurationCache.getInstance().pushConfig());

    targetResolutions.addAll(Arrays.asList(ResolutionPreset.values()));
    supportedFileFormats.addAll(Arrays.asList(SupportedFileFormat.values()));

    initRootLayout();

    showMainView();
    showSettingsView();
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
}

public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
.
.
.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

[image: Artifact output]

[image: IDE output]

Comment: Can you uncompress the jar to make sure that the fxml files are copied and are at the correct location in the jar?

Comment: I just unpacked the jar - and yes, it seems like every file is in its respective location.

Comment: Well, that would be easy to solve if you'd only provide an entire project (minimal version of course).

Comment: Have you started your app in command line to see if any exception is thrown ?

Comment: Haven't seen yet, so I ask: What OS you are using? And what Java Version you are using? (Try to answer with options like Windows/Linux/Mac OSX (32 or 64bit) and OpenJRE/JDK x86/x64 or OracleJRE/JDK x86/x64). And sure, you have to change your load method to contain a slash at the beginning of `getResource("/view/RootLayout.fxml")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide enough information to solve your problem, so here's an example that does work:

Create a package application and put this class into it:

*application/Main.java*

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/RootLayout.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Create a "RootLayout.fxml" in the package application.

*application/RootLayout.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="-125.0" layoutY="-143.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Button layoutX="134.0" layoutY="161.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

In Eclipse select

> Export -> Runnable JAR file -> Extract required libraries into
>   generated JAR

(of course you need to specify the proper launch configuration)

The generated JAR can be executed and has the nodes from the fxml.

Answer (score 3):

```
loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
```

try with

```
loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("/view/RootLayout.fxml"));
```

NetBeans the first variant will not compile in IDE

Comment: What has a "/" in a string got to do with compilation?

Comment: ups , not compile just run.

Comment: His problem isn't that it doesn't run in the IDE. His problem is that it doesn't run as a JAR.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the similar issue.It works well with the IDE but when I create a jar and try to run it was not able to load the fxml files. Following worked me.You can try and check if its getting the fxml files.

```
String fxml = "/com/test/fxmls/gui.fxml";
InputStream in = MycLass.class.getResourceAsStream(fxml);
if(in!=null){
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
loader.setLocation(MycLass.class.getResource(fxml));
BorderPane rootLayout = (BorderPane)loader.load(in);
}else{
  //log or output the error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think Resource files cannot be accessed from the jar file. So in this case your trying to load the fxml files from the jar which is not possible.  other wise follow the method that @Roland has suggested.